# Sorting a list of objects, TypeError: unorderable types

Tags: python, sorting, lambda

I am trying to sort a list of objects but i am receiving the following errors:

```
subredditlist.sort(key=lambda x: x.count)
  TypeError: unorderable types: builtin_function_or_method() < builtin_function_or_method()
```

The code in question:

main.py:

```
for k, v in smapped.items():
     rlist.append(objclist(k, v))
 rlist.sort(key=lambda x: x.count)
```

where subsmapped is a dictionary

objclist.py:

```
class objclist:
    def __init__(self, name, count):
        self.name = name
        self.count = count
```

Comment: How do you construct `subredditlist`?

Comment: added. the data comes from a dictionary which then gets used to create the objects that go into the list

Answer (score 4):

Given

```
class objclist:
    def __init__(self, name, count):
        self.name = name
        self.count = count
```

looks like you create instances of this class passing a function as `count` argument to the costructor.

```
for k, v in smapped.items():
     rlist.append(objclist(k, v))
 rlist.sort(key=lambda x: x.count)
```

Looks like `smapped` contains functions/methods in its values.

Comment: smapped is a dictionary.

Comment: Yes, it is a dictionary which contains a function in its values. Show how you construct `smapped`

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me as if `x.count` is a function, not a value.

If this is the case, change your lambda sort function to `lambda x: x.count()`.
If this is *not* the case, please add the definition of `subredditlist` to clarify your question.

Comment: count is supposed to be a value in the object.

Comment: _supposed to be_? Well, is it? :)

Answer (score 2):

To be sortable, a list must have objects which implement the `__lt__` method and are mutually comparable (i.e. [1,2,3] > "4" means nothing) -- or more precisely, the key function must return an object which are mutually comparable. Your key function is returning a method, which is not comparable. You probably meant to call the method `key=lambda x: x.count()`

Answer (score 2):

The error is complaining that the `key` is a "**builtin**_function_or_method()". This means that `x` is probably a `str`, `list`, `tuple` (are there other builtins with count methods?)

So the `v` you are passing to `objclist` is actually the `count` method of a builtin object.

Perhaps you forgot `()` somewhere when constructing `smapped.items()`